# String data from double single-quoted symbol in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I read some answers here and googled, but had no luck.

I have this:

```
''a
```

in scheme (Chez scheme to be exact), and I want to turn it into a string (it's a case in my to-string lambda).

Now, asking if it's a symbol (using the symbol predicate) yields a positive answer, so I know when to operate, but I can't do anything after that since there is no way to get the inner-quote itself.

So basically I can't find a way to turn ''a into "a".

Hopefully this is simple, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression:

```
''a
```

Is equivalent to this symbol definition (why the double quote, by the way? a single quote suffices):

```
(quote (quote a))
```

To turn it into a string, simply do this:

```
(symbol->string (cadr ''a))
=> "a"
```

Comment: OK, missed you cadr, will try and update, thanks!

Update: IT WORKS! :-)

Comment: @ReutSharabani see my updated answer. Anyway, I think there's something weird in that code, suspicious to say the least

Comment: If you HAVE to know I'm writing a compiler using scheme, and the raw input is supplied with a quote.

So, in the REPL loop - a simple quoted expression evaluation would be generated by the user using the input "'a", but it would be quoted again so that I can read it properly (cause we're not dealing only with quoted expressions...), producing ''a.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ReutSharabani The usual way for dealing with "not only quoted expressions" is to use `quasiquote`. Then, things are quoted by default, but you can break out of the quoting using `unquote` and `unquote-splicing`. Much tidier than the double-quoting thing you've got.

Comment: Yes, that's mostly what I've used, but how owuld you quote a quote then?

(meaning, the user inserts a quote, how would you know, upon scanning and parsing, it's a quote? everything is a quote).